# Django template tag conventions

Tags: html, django

Is there any difference between the following Django template tags, or are both equivalent? They basically have differing quotation marks:

`<a href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}#section0">`

and

`<a href='{% url "edit_profile" %}#section0'>`

*Note: #section0 is an [HTML anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of quotation mark is strictly required - you may use both of them. The only rule you must follow is to use the same quotation mark at the beginning and at the end of statement.